Не получается подключить open cv в visual studio 2017
Пытаюсь подключить opencv к opencv к visual studio, прописаны пути к папке lib, подключены файлы lib, возникает проблема с dll файлами. Выводится сообщение об ошибке из-за отсутствия opencv490dll и "Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FFFEEB6C5A0 (ntdll.dll) в Project8.exe: 0xC0000135: Unable to Locate DLL." Посоветовали добавить к переменной path путь к папке bin с dll в open cv, но не помогло. Что можно сделать?
